# Can I use multiple segues with one UITableViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a *UITableView* listing multiple types of objects, and I'd like to segue to a different view depending on which type of object the user selects.

Is it possible to do this by using multiple segues, and, if so, how?

Comment: Static or dynamic cells?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course ! Define all your segues on your storyboard, by ctrl-dragging **from the tableViewController** (not a row, the tableViewController itself) to the next view. Give them IDs, so you know which one to call. When all your segues are defined visually, go to the code. In your tableView's delegate, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, simply call the segue you want, by checking `indexPath.row` :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue0" sender:self];
                break;
        case 1: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue1" sender:self];
                break;
        [...]
        default: break;
    }
}
```

That way, the segue with the ID "Segue0" will be fired when the user selects the first row, and so on.

You can also add the line : `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] animated:YES];` at the beginning of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so the row does not remain selected after the user touched it !

Edit : This works for both static and dynamic cells ! Be careful to ctrl-drag your segue from the tableViewController, not a cell !

Comment: ctrl clicking on the tableView doesn't seem to do it. Does it make a difference if I am segue-ing to a viewController instead of a view? (creating segues from the rows seems to work just fine)

Comment: Maybe you mean use the tableViewController? The rows work, and the tableViewController works. The controller makes more sense to me as a place for the segues, too.

Comment: Yes, that wasn't really clear. It's in fact the tableViewController, I just wanted to say that I'm not sure it works when you start your segue from a cell, some unexpected behavior may happen. I think if you segue from a cell with static cells, you don't need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath (not so sure about that though)..

Comment: Well, I just saw your answer, it's kind of what I was trying to talk about, if you try to use a bit of both solutions, it may not work very well :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation would be to:

- Create a specialized reusable prototypeCell in the table view for each type of object you're going to store (either drag a new cell object from your Object Library, or click on the existing default one and copy/paste). Remember to fill in a unique Identifier for each reusable cell, you'll need to be able to tell them apart later on 
  (probably making a call to

  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CellIdentifier0"];

inside

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView(UITableView *)tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

- Ctrl-click on each prototype cell, and drag to create a segue for each one
- The segues will get fired automatically, just have to handle them as they get fired

This works if you have a single transition per reusable cell, which is likely to cover many cases.