# UITableView with different views for every button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am writing an iPhone app that is supposed to create a TableView with 5 buttons. Each button is supposed to open up a different TableView.

I am using storyboards for my application, and the storyboard view controller shows only one button, so how can I link each button in my app to a separate detailviewcontroller?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you are using seque and your button is in UITableViewCell?

Comment: I am using UITableView with 5 cell buttons. I need to connect each of these cells using a segue to 5 different detail view controllers.

Comment: do u mean 5 buttons in each cell/row..? or 5 rows with 1 button in each..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each button to trigger different controller than you have to create 5 seque with different destination controller and than when button is tapped , use following function to show different controller.

```
– performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

Give each seque a different identifier and based on which button is tapped ( can be check using button tag) perform different seque and hence show different controller...

To pass data between viewController which is a common task, i am surprised you have not done it before :
goto this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) .

Comment: So, I understood that part. That I need to write 5 different viewcontrollers with 5 corresponding Segues.

Now, my question is that I am selecting 1 prototype cell in the tableview of the parent tableviewcontroller. That means I can have only 1 CellIdentifier which is mentioned in the storyboard itself. That being the case, how do I identify which Cell triggered which segue?

Comment: you will be performing the seque programmetically based on cell's row number which is tapped...

Comment: Actually, from a TableView I can only create 1 segue to a detail view controller. I can't have multiple segues coming from 1 prototype cell and going to multiple detail view controllers.

Also, I am a bit confused how to use performSeguewithIdentifer function. I set a string called identifierOfSegueToCall depending on the tablerow selected. After this, do I have to write the full definition for performSegueWithIdentifier or I have to define prepareForSegue?

Comment: From Tableviewcontroller , make 5 seques to detailViewController( dont use cell to connect to seque for now) just give identifier to seque and performSeguewithIdentifer when this cell is tapped...you can see how to use performSeguewithIdentifer in documentation just perform it on self(UIViewController object).

Comment: I got how to do that from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303485/can-i-use-multiple-segues-with-one-uitableviewdelegate.

Now, how can I pass data between the view controllers?

Comment: Have edited My answer and has added a link .go through it and upvote and correct My answer if that solves your query...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have figured it out