# Segue to UITableView depending on Row Selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView which contains an array of 3 items. Upon user selection, I need each of these three items to segue to a different UITableView. For example:

First Scene is the table which contains the list: Weather, Intelligence, Fuels Status
Second scene would be:

For when a user selects weather, segue to a table which contains the array "daily maps, fire potential, etc."
For when a user selects intelligence, segue to a table which contains the array "current active fires, new initial attacks, etc."

and so forth.

I have been told I could use different UITableViewCells for each prototype cell but I'm sure there is an easier way that I am simply not grasping. All current segues were done in storyboard. Could someone please elaborate on how I should be segueing from scene to scene (at a beginner-intermediate level of understanding)?

Root

```
#import "PSMenu_TableViewController.h"
#import "WXMenu_TableViewController.h"
#import "PSTableViewCell.h"

@interface PSMenu_TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PSMenu_TableViewController
@synthesize PSMenuImage = _PSMenuImage;
@synthesize PSMenuText = _PSMenuText;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.PSMenuText = [[NSArray alloc]
                  initWithObjects:@"Weather",
                  @"Intelligence",
                  @"Fuels Status",
                  nil];

    self.PSMenuImage = [[NSArray alloc]
                  initWithObjects:@"RMACC_114x114.png",
                  @"RMACC_114x114.png",
                  @"RMACC_114x114.png",
                  nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_PSMenuText count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"rootTableCell";

    PSTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == 0) {
        cell = [[PSTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.rootLabel.text = [self.PSMenuText
                           objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    UIImage *rootPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:
                          [self.PSMenuImage objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];

    cell.rootImage.image = rootPhoto;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Use indexPath to retrieve info that needs to be passed along to next view controller
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"getWeather" sender:self];
}


@end
```

One of the .m files I am trying to segue to:

```
#import "WXMenu_TableViewController.h"
#import "DWO_TableViewController.h"


@interface WXMenu_TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation WXMenu_TableViewController
{
//Define array for weather products list
    NSArray *allwx;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Define the weather products list
    allwx = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Daily Weather", @"Fire Potential", @"Multi-Media Briefing", @"Sig. Fire Potential",@"Seasonal Outlook", @"Fire Season Broadcast", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Set table size to one section.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //When Weather is clicked on previous VC, the allwx list is displayed
    if ([_weathertable isEqualToString:@"Weather"]) {
        return [allwx count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *pstableID = @"MainCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:pstableID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:pstableID];
    }

    if ([_weathertable isEqualToString:@"Weather"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [allwx objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDWODetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DWO_TableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.dailywxtable = [allwx objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.title = destViewController.dailywxtable;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: See this for more elegant methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303485/can-i-use-multiple-segues-with-one-uitableviewdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can segue to a single `UITableViewController` here and make it display respective contents according to the category chosen. This might help you.

In your Destination View Controller, you can declare a variable and use it in your `prepareForSegue` method as shown to identify what type of content do you want to see on your destination view controller.

```
destController.varName = @"setYourTypeHere";
```

Now you can also set the variable value here based on the Row you are clicking in your tableview.

And in your Destination View controller, you can check this value using `switch` or `if...else` cases and bind the appropriate data as per your requirement.

Comment: This got me on the right track, although I am still unsure how to perform different segues  for each value in my main array with one prototype cell. I can not segue more than once from the prototype cell. Also, how would I go about creating the if/else statement for the segues

Comment: Actually there will be only one segue to the destination View controller. You just have to play with the variable value to check what type of content you need. So when your prepareForSegue is called, just pass the appropriate value in the variable and check that value on the destination side. Make a switch case or if...else for those values.

Comment: So I should have three separate segue statements in my root controller with varnames such as "weather" "intel" and "fuels status". Then, in my next scene, a UITableViewController, I would include the arrays for each of the tables I wish to create based off those three items.What happens when I want one or more tables based off the new scene? How might I set up the prepareForSegue action to include each array item?

Comment: No. Let there be only one segue. Take a NSString variable in your destination controller and play with those varnames using that variable like I explained in my answer.So basically, it's like whichever cell you tap in the list, the segue will be the same and it will take you to the same destination, but the type of data requested by that variable will change.

Comment: Wow. I'm sorry I got so fixated on the damn segues! Thanks for your help! This should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you wire up each destination not to the prototype tableview cell, but to the view controller itself (little yellow box on left side of the title bar of the view controller in the storyboard).

Name each segue with a meaningful name, and then in your "didSelect" delegate method you can perform a segue using:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myNamedSegue" sender:self];
```