# XCode Table View vs Button for Menu Solution w/ Different ViewController Destinations

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, viewcontroller

I swear I tried to find an answer to this question but can't seem to lick this issue.

I have a table view that I would like to take the user to 4 different viewcontrollers as each destination viewcontroller from the menu needs very different functionality/layout.  However, at present I can only go to one view controller.  If I simply put in buttons instead of the table view I can accomplish this but this doesn't seem like best practice and I enjoy some of the clean/tightness of the table view.  Also, I do not need to pass anything from the parent viewcontroller.

I'm new, if my newb question wasn't obvious enough.  If there is a tutorial/page/resource you can point me to that'd be greatly appreciated by myself and the non-profit I'm trying to do this for :)

Thanks for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  In case someone else has this problem and has stumbled onto my question before seeing it answered elsewhere.  A newb like myself didn't know enough about segues.  You'll need background on creating segues in storyboard from the parent view controller to the children with unique segue IDs and then take care of the rest in the .m file of the parent.  Also be careful about assigning the delegate of your table view as this was another silly oversight of mine.

Here's the link I found most helpful.
[Can I use multiple segues with one UITableViewDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303485/can-i-use-multiple-segues-with-one-uitableviewdelegate)