# Go from UITableView(not a UITableViewController) to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`.
When the user presses a cell inside the `UITableView` I would like to show another `UIViewController`. So I have `UIViewController` "A", with `UITableView` "A" inside and I would like to click a cell in `UITableView` "A" and be pushed to `UIViewController` "B". I tried simply connecting a segue from the `UITableViewCell` to the `UIViewController` but this results in nothing happening when the cell is pressed. I also tried the following code unsuccessfully. Again, nothing happening, no errors.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    AlbumsViewController *albumsViewControllerObj = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlbumsViewController"];
   [albumsViewControllerObj performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlbumDetail" sender:self];

}
```

All of the advice I have found so far involves going from a Table View Controller to another view, which I know how to do and have never had a problem with. For some reason though I am having issues moving from a Table View to another View Controller. If it matters (and I think it may) the delegate and datasource of the TableView "A" is View Controller "A". Any advice would be great, thank you!

Comment: Did you set up the delegate of the tableView?

Comment: can  u check my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple segues with one UITableViewDelegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303485/can-i-use-multiple-segues-with-one-uitableviewdelegate)

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 2):

First,set the `delegate` and `datasource` to self.

Second,just drag a segue from ViewControllerA to ControllerB

Third,just perform segue when select

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlbumDetail" sender:nil];
    }
```

Then,in `prepareForSegue`,pass data to destinnatinVC

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if (segue.identifier == yourid) {
        ViewControllerB *  = segue.destinationViewController;
        //Pass data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up the delegate and datasource, either programmatically like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.datasource = self;
}
```

Or you can do it in the storyboard by ctrl click and drag from your tableView to the viewController.

Then you can segue to viewController b, programmatically or in the storyboard.

Porgrammatically:

First go to the storyboard and ctrl click and drag from viewController a to viewController b. Then in your code write the following:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextViewControllerID" sender:nil];
}
```

StoryBoard:

ctrl click and drag from the cell to viewController b.

Answer (score 0):

Check first Any chance you accidentally typed `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`? .Check out if the method name of what you expect of being `didSelect` may accidentally be gotten `didDeselect` in some way.

in the `SimpleTableController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

In `SimpleTableViewController.m`  .check if  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called or not by doing as below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"You've selected a row" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        // Display Alert Message
        [messageAlert show];

    }
```

set the `delegate` and `datasource` .

[image]